# Multi answer quiz in jquery with custom alert

Tags: jquery, if-statement, alert

Kinda new to jquery and I have a multiple answer quiz question. It is working correctly until I add a custom error message.

The question has multiple correct answers that gets checked against a variable at the top. I want the question to also check if they selected all checkboxes or no checkboxes. It gives the user feedback via an alert message.

Below is my jsfiddle... Click the "submit" button without checking any boxes and you will see the custom alert shows twice (the second alert error). Then comment out the first "window.alert" lines of the js code that replaces the alert box and it will show one error and then the other (ideal way).

Is there a better way I can construct my if statements to combine checking the amount of boxes check and the correct answers at the same time?

http://jsfiddle.net/bregm/6/

```
         <p>Please select the 5 correct answers:</p>


    <label><input type="checkbox" name="q1" class="wrong"></input>Answer 0  </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="q1" id="q1-a"></input>Answer 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="q1" class="wrong"></input>Answer 2 </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="q1" id="q1-b"></input>Answer 3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="q1" id="q1-c" ></input>Answer 4 </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="q1" id="" class="wrong"></input>Answer 5</label>    
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="q1" id="" class="wrong"></input>Answer 6</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="q1" id="q1-d"  ></input>Answer 7</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="q1" id="q1-e"  ></input>Answer 8</label>

<br />
 <button class="submit1">Submit1</button>
  <div id="messageBox"> </div> 

#messageBox {
 position: fixed;
top:40%;
left: 20px;
width: 240px;
height:auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px; 
background-color:#F93;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 6px;
display: none;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px #000;
padding: 1em;

}
window.alert = function(message) { 
        $('#messageBox').text(message).fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
     //comment out this bit of code and you can see my issue.
    }

    $(function(){
        //correct answers stored here by id
         var rules = ['q1-a,q1-b,q1-c,q1-d,q1-e'];


    $('.submit1').click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
            ///checks to see how many checkboxes have been clicked
            var countchecked1 = $("input[name=q1]:checked").length;
              if(countchecked1 == 0) 
                {
               alert("You have not selected any checkboxes.");
                } 
              if(countchecked1 == 9) 
                {
               alert("Cheating.. You can't select all the boxes.");
               $('input[name=q1]:checked').removeAttr('checked'); 
                return false;
                }

    //check correct answers from var above
           if( $('input[name=q1]:checked').map(function(i,v) { return v.id; }).get().join(',') == rules[0] ) {
                alert("Correct! you selected the correct answers. ");
                return false;
              } 
             else
              {   
                $('input[type="checkbox"].wrong:checked').parent('label').addClass('highlight');     
                $('.wrong:checked').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('.wrong:checked').removeAttr('checked'); 
                alert("Incorrect... Please try again");
                return false;
             }


         });
    });
```

Comment: The solution to 2 alert box is `if(countchecked1 == 0) { alert("You have not selected any checkboxes.");return false;}`

I am still reading the code to find out possible better way to construct if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change all the `if`s into `else if`s. That way, the code is finished after having found a match. Otherwise, the code still continues to run even after already having met a condition. It is not only more efficient, but necessary in this case.

```
$('.submit1').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        ///checks to see how many checkboxes have been clicked
        var countchecked1 = $("input[name=q1]:checked").length;
          if(countchecked1 == 0) 
            {
           alert("You have not selected any checkboxes.");
            } 
          else if(countchecked1 == 9) 
            {
           alert("Cheating.. You can't select all the boxes.");
           $('input[name=q1]:checked').removeAttr('checked'); 
            return false;
            }

//check correct answers from var above
       else if( $('input[name=q1]:checked').map(function(i,v) { return v.id; }).get().join(',') == rules[0] ) {
            alert("Correct! you selected the correct answers. ");
            return false;
          } 
         else
          {   
            $('input[type="checkbox"].wrong:checked').parent('label').addClass('highlight');     
            $('.wrong:checked').attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeAttr('checked');
            alert("Incorrect... Please try again");
            return false;
         }


     });
```

Also use chaining so that Jquery doesn't have to search through the DOM tree again:

```
$('.wrong:checked').attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeAttr('checked');
```

And if I were you, I wouldn't allow more than 5 checkmarks at a time.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/bregm/9/

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much! Huge help! My next steps will be to figure out how to store checkboxes in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think Even below code will do the trick as you are already adding `wrong` class to all wrong answers

```
   $('.submit1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ///checks to see how many checkboxes have been clicked
    var $inputq = $("input[name=q1]");
    var $checked = $inputq.filter(":checked");

    if ($checked.length == $inputq.length) {
        alert("Cheating.. You can't select all the boxes.");
        $checked.removeAttr('checked');
        return false;
    }
    var wrongChecked = $('input[type="checkbox"].wrong:checked');
    if (wrongChecked.length > 0) {
        wrongChecked.parent('label').addClass('highlight');
        wrongChecked.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        wrongChecked.removeAttr('checked');
        alert("Incorrect... Please try again");
        return false;
    } else if ($checked.length == 5) {
        alert("Correct! you selected the correct answers. ");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("You have not selected All correct checkboxes.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bregm/8/

Comment: Thanks Rahul!  I will give both these a try. Appreciate your help!